# How to make changes on Wordpress site locally on live site?

Tags: version-control, workflow

I would like to set up a System where I can clone a live website and work on it locally and then when I'm satisfied and the changes are approved, I can send or sync those changes with the live site. I'm currently watching gitHub tutorials, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make changes in live site with local install you need to setup a synchronization system. which synchronize static files and database files.
You can use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) for version control.

[Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-sync-a-local-remote-wordpress-blog-using-version-control--wp-22135) is a great article for Sync A Local and A Remote WordPress Blog using version control.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a WordPress deployment system, such as Mark Jaquith's [WP Stack](http://www.knewton.com/tech/blog/2012/07/announcing-wp-stack/).